# How to wrap elements in a group of items with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following markup:

```
<article class="linkWrapper" data-group="1">
  <a href="#">...</a>
</article>

<article class="linkWrapper" data-group="1">
  <a href="#">...</a>
</article>

<article class="linkWrapper" data-group="2">
  <a href="#">...</a>
</article>

<article class="linkWrapper" data-group="2">
  <a href="#">...</a>
</article>

<article class="linkWrapper" data-group="2">
  <a href="#">...</a>
</article>
```

And I'd like to wrap these `linkWrapper's` with another parent element - `<section class="linkGroup">..</section>` based on the `data-group` attribute. How can I do this with `jQuery`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way you could do it:

```js
    // Cache object which stores which groups we've processed
    var groupedSections = {};
    $(".linkWrapper[data-group]").each(function() {
        var group = $(this).attr("data-group");
        // For each found group, check to see if we have processed that group
        if(!groupedSections[group]) {
            // If not, wrap the matching selectors...
            $(".linkWrapper[data-group='"+group+"']").wrapAll("<section>");
            // Store that group in the cache object:
            groupedSections[group] = true;
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article class="linkWrapper" data-group="1">
  <a href="#">...</a>
</article>

<article class="linkWrapper" data-group="1">
  <a href="#">...</a>
</article>

<article class="linkWrapper" data-group="2">
  <a href="#">...</a>
</article>

<article class="linkWrapper" data-group="2">
  <a href="#">...</a>
</article>

<article class="linkWrapper" data-group="2">
  <a href="#">...</a>
</article>
```

Comment: @Xeen You're welcome. I updated the answer to only iterate the objects once. The previous answer iterated twice for pretty much no reason :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery wrap function](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)

```
$(".linkWrapper").wrap("<section class='linkGroup'> .. </section>");
```

Comment: OP says he wants to wrap base on `data-group`

Answer (score 0):

Example : [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/SzymonDziewonski/pen/yNpoVW)

Blue is your `.linkWrapper` and border red is `section` wrap

```
  $(".linkWrapper").each(function(){
    $(this).wrap("<section></section>");
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$('.linkWrapper[data-group]').wrap('<section class="linkGroup" />');
```

`[data-group]` is only used because the value may be anything and you want to wrap those having any value.

See [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector) and [wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap)